# How to get all element of a class but not of another class?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

In my DOM I have these elements:

```
<div class="myclass yourclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass yourclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass yourclass"></div>
```

I need to get all div of myclass but NOT of yourclass ( so in the case above I need to get 3 elements ).
I tryed this but doesn't work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myclass:not([.yourclass])')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `[]` in `querySelectorAll`, it is invalid syntax.

You can use any CSS selector as it is in `querySelectorAll`. See the demo below.(colored by using CSS, see `console` for javascript result)

```js
var myClassElements = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass:not(.yourclass)');
console.log(myClassElements);
```

```css
div {
  color: red;
}
.myclass:not(.yourclass) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass yourclass">a</div>
<div class="myclass">b</div>
<div class="myclass">c</div>
<div class="myclass yourclass">d</div>
<div class="myclass">e</div>
<div class="myclass yourclass">f</div>
```

[**:not()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)